# Reduce jerk in opengl es Android

Tags: android, bitmapimage

I am animating bitmap image on in my screen it shows little bit jerks but when i connect it to LCD the jerks are pretty much obvious. Following is the code. Is their a way to make it jerk free
//this is square class

```
public class Square {
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;   // buffer holding the vertices
private float vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,        // V1 - bottom left
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,        // V2 - top left
         1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,        // V3 - bottom right
         1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f         // V4 - top right
};

private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;  // buffer holding the texture coordinates
private float texture[] = {         
        // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
        0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
        0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
        1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
        1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)
};

/** The texture pointer */
private int[] textures = new int[1];

public Square() {
    // a float has 4 bytes so we allocate for each coordinate 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // allocates the memory from the byte buffer
    vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

    // fill the vertexBuffer with the vertices
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);

    // set the cursor position to the beginning of the buffer
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.position(0);
}

/**
 * Load the texture for the square
 * @param gl
 * @param context
 */
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    // loading texture

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.car);
    // generate one texture pointer
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    // ...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // create nearest filtered texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE

    // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap 
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Clean up
    bitmap.recycle();
}


/** The draw method for the square with the GL context */
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    // bind the previously generated texture
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // Point to our buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    // Point to our vertex buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    //Disable the client state before leaving
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

}

//this is renderer

```
public class GlRenderer implements Renderer {

private Square      square;     // the square
private Context     context;
private float mTransY = -8;

/** Constructor to set the handed over context */
public GlRenderer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    // initialise the square
    this.square = new Square();
}


public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // clear Screen and Depth Buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Reset the Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    // Drawing
    gl.glTranslatef(mTransY, 0.0f, -10.0f);     // move 5 units INTO the screen
                                            // is the same as moving the camera 5 units away
    System.gc();                                        // otherwise it will be too large
    square.draw(gl);                        // Draw the triangle
    mTransY += 0.1f;

    if (mTransY>=8.0f)
        mTransY=-8.0f;
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
    }

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

    //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
}


public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // Load the texture for the square
    square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    //Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

    //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 

}
```

}

// this is activity

```
public class Run extends Activity {

/** The OpenGL view */
private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // requesting to turn the title OFF
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // making it full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Initiate the Open GL view and
    // create an instance with this activity
    glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

    // set our renderer to be the main renderer with
    // the current activity context
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new GlRenderer(this));
    setContentView(glSurfaceView);
}
```

}

Comment: It was showing merory clean up at intervals therefore i added system.gc to clean on every step but it was of no use